# use xtile by year using weights

Tags: stata

I have data with income variable, with weight, and I want to calculate the 5% quantiles by year.
Is there a way to do that?

For the weight I can use regular `xtile`:

```
xtile quan = salary [aw=weight], n(20)
```

And for the years I can use `xtile` from `egenmore`:

```
egen quan = xtile(salary), by(year) nq(20)
```

But how can I do it for weights and by year together?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `weights()` option, as stated in `help egenmore`:

```
clear
set more off

sysuse auto
keep mpg foreign weight

// egenmore
egen mpg4 = xtile(mpg), by(foreign) nq(4) weights(weight)

// compare with xtile
xtile mpg4_1 = mpg [aweight=weight] if foreign, nq(4)
xtile mpg4_2= mpg [aweight=weight] if !foreign, nq(4)
egen mpg42 = rowtotal(mpg4_1 mpg4_2)

assert mpg4 == mpg42

sort foreign mpg weight
list, sepby(foreign)
```

In the ado-file for `egen`'s `xtile` function, you can check how weights are set:

```
if "`weights'" ~= "" {
        local weight "[aw = `weights']"
}
```

See `viewsource _gxtile.ado`.

Comment: I missed it- Thanks a lot!